# Загрузка изображения kivy, если не знаю начального пути файла

Tags: python, mysql, kivy

Делаю приложение, пользователь загружает свою фотографию, я ее сохраняю на сервер. Затем мне надо как-то вывести эту фотографию в приложение, но дело в том, что непонятно как это сделать, ибо изначально пути я не знаю и у фотография каждого пользователя сохраняется в разных папках с разными именами. Везде где нашел какую-то информацию пишут с известным путем к этому файлу. Есть ли какое-то решение данной проблемы по типу такого:

```
AsyncImage:
    source: newpath
```

где newpath это наш неизвестный путь к файлу.
Так же можно рассмотреть вариант загрузки с базы данных MySql.
Буду очень признателен, если поможете...

Answer (score 0):

При запуске приложения, Вам нужно сделать функцию, которая будет автоматически создавать папку. В этой папке у Вас будут храниться все файлы, которые были отправлены / получены. Путь создания папки Вы сами задаете. Создание папки с помощью библиотеки os:
import os

os.mkdir(“C://Directory”)